# Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'microsoft.web.infrastructure.dll' (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I debugged my website using `asp.net (c#)` and there was this:

> warning: Unable to update auto-refresh reference
>   'microsoft.web.infrastructure.dll'

Despite that, the website still runs smoothly. How do I resolve this warning?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd99d83b-7ee5-4ca7-b64c-4064153112bd/warning-unable-to-update-autorefresh-reference-vs2013?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today while having the same issue and wanted to share just in case. Looking at the properties for the dll I discovered that the refresh path was referencing a location that was unreachable. Not sure this is sound advice, but I deleted the refresh file for `microsoft.web.infrastructure.dll` and the warning went away.